# Как добавить строку в DataTable вместо удаленной

Tags: c#

Имеется

```
DataTable dt
```

В нем есть парочка строк. Удалить строку я могу так:

```
dtRows[0].Delete().
```

**Вопрос**: Как именно вместо удаленной строки добавить другую, именно по этому же индексу?

Comment: Через Delete вы не удаляете строку, а помечаете на удаление. Свой индекс в коллекции строк она сохранит. Зачем вам завязка на индекс?

Answer (score 1):

В `DataTable` есть возможность вставить `DataRow` по индексу.

Пример кода:

```
DataTable dt; 
//.....
dt.Rows.InsertAt(new DataRow(...), 0);
```